getting Warning: Error in : C stack usage 7970544 is too close to the limit when running flexdashboard
In my dashboard I source an R script that contains a print statement. The printed statement is a string which contains the name of the file being sourced. Why am I getting this is the error?
Warning: Error in : C stack usage  7970544 is too close to the limit
Here's a minimal working example:
---
title: "Dashboard"
output:
flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
orientation: rows
dev: CairoPNG
runtime: shiny
---
```{r setup, cache = FALSE }
library(shiny)
source('in.R') 
```
Inputs 
===================================================================================================================
```{r}
shiny::radioButtons("x" ,h5("some button"), c("no" = 0,"yes" = 1), selected = 1   )  
```

# and here is the contents of "in.R": 
```
 print(      ' foo bar  "in.R"' )
```

I didn't expect any issue because I thought I could put nearly anything in the string and it wouldn't get evaluated/checked/etc. Interestingly, if the sourced file is modified in any of these ways, then it runs fine:
print(     ' foo bar   in.R     '                    ) 
print(      ' foo bar   "this_file_DOES_NOT_exist.R"' )
print(      ' foo bar   "this_file_DOES_exist.R"'     ) 

It seems like this error only happens when the sourced file shows up in the string being printed with quotes around it.
To be clear: I don't need a work around; just an explanation. If "in.R" is sourced from an R script (ie not flexdashboard), then there's no problem, so I assume this is related to flexdashboard in some way?

It doesn't seem to be specific to flexdashboard. The same error occurs if you change the output to output: html_document

It's odd. So if you have file.R you will get an error if you include "file.R", "in.R" and "inner.R" in the file. It doesn't have to be a print() but it does have to have quotes. For example x <- "in.R" also seems to trigger the same error no matter the file name.

Seems specific to runtime: shiny. If you comment that out, you don't get the error. But I still can't figure out why. If you run shiny directly it doesn't have a problem sourcing the file.
